# get the value of a managed metadata item

Tags: powershell, managed-metadata

I have a column called mark it is a managed metadata column. I want to print out the values of this column, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the script which will get the value of MM column from a list.
PowerShell Script to pull records from a SP List and put them in a csv file including the MM columns called PName.

```
$exportlist = @()
$Mylist.Items | foreach {
    $Value = $_["PName"] -as [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue]; 
    $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        "AName" = $_["AName"]
        "PName" = $Value.Label  
        "Address 1" = $_["Address 1"]
        "Address 2" = $_["Address 1"]
        "Address 3" = $_["Address 3"]
    }
    $exportlist += $obj     
}
$exportlist | Export-Csv -path 'C:\AData.csv'
```

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/17a45653-146d-4e58-8679-9c3dd5125a12/powershell-script-convert-managed-metadata-column-value-to-string?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

if you want to use the java script then follow this instruction:

http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2013/02/retrieving-sharepoint-list-column-managed-metadata-javascript/